# DOMExecption error when installing service worker

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I'm trying to install my service worker, but I keep getting the error `DOMException` when installing my worker using

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                console.log('Queing Worker...');
                window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    console.log('Registering Worker...');
                    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
                        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
                    });
                });
            }
```

what should I do?

Comment: Is your server work attempting to manipulation the DOM?

Comment: No @RandyCasburn

Comment: Sorry, the auto correct monster struck...my question was _supposed to be_: is your service worker attempting to manipulate the DOM. I'll take it your answer was to that question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ALEEF02 What kind of error do you see?

Comment: `DOMException` is what I get @piecioshka

Comment: @ALEEF02 oh, but please put more details, because `DOMException` has a lot of types due to https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dfn-DOMException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
Service workers can't be behind a redirect
This was only found when trying to put the code directly into console